# How do I calculate lumens of a specific RGB light source from watts per square meter per steradian?

Tags: visible-light

## Context

I am trying to understand irradiance calculations for interior lighting in Blender software and got stuck with inputting light strength in lumens, because the lights in the software take watts per square meter per steradian. We are talking only about visible light. Virtual lights in the software have strength that is set in watts per square meter per steradian and an RGB color in linear color space with REC.709 primaries(610nm, 555nm and 465nm) although brightness of typical light sources are usually given in lumens.

## Example

So let's say I have a spot light that has a strength of 3 watts per square meter per steradian and it's color is defined by digital RGB color values of 3 wavelenghts: 610nm, 555nm and 465nm. Let's say the color is expressed as RGB(0.499938, 0.367322, 0.220984). Its cone angle is 45 degrees. Let's say it's radius is 0.025m. How many lumens is that? How do I calculate that?

Let's say I want that same light to have a strength of 900 lumens. How many watts per square meter per steradian is that? How do I calculate that?

Comment: It seems I lack very basic physics knowledge and I am not even familiar with greek alphabet in the formulas I find online which makes it quite a bit harder to understand quickly. An example of the calculations would speed up my learning process a lot. If asking for it is not against Physics Stack Exchange guidelines, I would be grateful for it. If it is, well, tough luck for me, I'll have to figure it out slowly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you have 1 watt of 555nm (green) light then you have 683 lumens. Lumen is more of a source measurement ... if you spread it over a large or small cone it does not matter you still have 1 lumen.

Comment: rec 709 is about 200 to 300 lumens per watt .... can't recall exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion factor you need is the [luminous efficacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficacy). You need to know the full spectrum of the light to compute it. Tristimulus values (such as Rec.709 RGB) aren't enough, unless you make additional assumptions. For example, if you happen to know that the light has a blackbody spectrum, then you can work out the temperature from the RGB color and the luminous efficacy from the temperature.

If you assume that the illuminant is a mixture of 610nm, 555nm and 465nm monochromatic lights then you can calculate the luminous efficacy as well, but that assumption is extremely unlikely to be true. The Rec.709 primaries aren't monochromatic lights of those or any other wavelengths, and even if they were, RGB values elsewhere in the cube wouldn't necessarily come from spectra that are linear mixture of those lights.

All of this is irrelevant, though, since Blender shouldn't be using watts to begin with, it should be using lumens. If the rigid-body simulation demands masses in pounds, you shouldn't use the local gravity where the scene is set to do the conversion. You should use whatever fixed conversion factor they're using internally.

Unfortunately for my theory, [this page on blender.org](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html) has a table of suggested lumen-watt conversions in which the ratio is nowhere close to any fixed value. Either they don't know what they're talking about or I don't.

My advice, for what it's worth, is to use a simple fixed factor like 300 lm/W. As long as you're consistent, the value shouldn't matter since it's equivalent to a change in the overall exposure.

Answer (score 2):

There is radiant flux, measured in Watts, regardless of whether those Watts are visible. Then there is luminous flux, measured in lumens. It is calculated by adding up the Watts at each wavelength weighted by how sensitive the eye is at that wavelength. Infrared light might have a high radiant flux, but it the luminous flux will be $0$.

For more, see [What do CCT, CIE, and SPD mean in LED lighting?](https://luminusdevices.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403685063437-What-do-CCT-CIE-and-SPD-mean-in-LED-lighting)

Comment: We are only talking about visible light. The input in watts per square meter per steradian is only for visible light since it's software for rendering CG and the input is RGB color in "linear color space with REC.709 primaries". I suppose the value represents luminous flux and is only expressed as radiant flux. Would that make sense? Could the question be answer in that context?

Comment: I believe the primaries consist of 3 dominant wavelenghts: 610nm, 555nm and 465nm.

Comment: This is helpful though, thank you.

Comment: I face a ridiculous problem of not being familiar with greek alphabet in the formulas at the moment. But, yes, I do have RGB color in specific digital color space that defines the spectrum of the light source, so I did understand that part. I am a multimedia designer, not a physicist.

Comment: I edited the question.